# Validating a Password

Tags: java, string, validation, boolean

I want to check whether a password has at least 8 characters and consist of numbers and letters only. 
The problem here is even though I entered a valid password it says 'Invalid' all the time. Here's the code. Thanks.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String pw;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a password: ");
    pw = sc.next();

    if(isValid(pw)==true)
    {
        System.out.println("Valid Password");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Password");
    }

}

public static boolean isValid(String pw)
{
    if(pw.length()<8)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int x=0; x<pw.length(); x++)
        {

            return Character.isLetterOrDigit(pw.charAt(x));

        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: did you debug? What is `pw` if you enter a password, where does the code actually return, etc.

Comment: You realize your loop where you are checking for `isLetterOrDigit` returns on the first check, right?

Comment: Your loop logic is ***completely*** off. Please debug your code to see what crazy useless returns it does. Or even better: write some tests and see which fail.-

Answer (score 3):

Logic of your code is correct except return statement in 'for' loop in isValid method. Here is edited code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String pw;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a password: ");
    pw = sc.next();

    if(isValid(pw))
    {
        System.out.println("Valid Password");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Password");
    }

}

public static boolean isValid(String pw)
{
    if(pw.length()<8)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int x=0; x<pw.length(); x++)
        {
            if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(pw.charAt(x)))
                 return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that your code does not print 'invalid' if your password is valid but could print 'valid' for some invalid passwords such as a@@@@@@@@

Answer (score 2):

You're returning the result within the first iteration of the loop, rather you should make a flag variable and return the result at the end of the loop or you could invert the `if` condition within the loop and return *false* if that evaluates to *true* and if it does not then return *true* at the end of the loop.

```
public static boolean isValid(String password){
    if(password.length() < 8)
        return false;

    for(int x = 0; x < password.length(); x++)
        if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(password.charAt(x)))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```